# Java - generic type

Tags: java, generics

For this question, we assume that is possible to extend the class String in java. In the next code:

```
T getId ( ) ;
void setId (T t ) ;
}
public class Person implements Identifiable <String> { . . . }
public class Car implements Identifiable <Integer> { . . . }
public class UTFString extends String { . . . }
public class Tourist implements Identifiable <UTFString> { . . . }

Identifiable <Y> z ;
if ( . . . ) {
     z = new Person ( ) ;
} else {
    z = new Tourist ( ) ;
}
z.setId(new UTFString(…))
```

I was asked what is the correct type of Y. I know that the type of `Y`, should be: `? super UTF-STRING`, meaning: `Identifiable <? super UTF-STRING> z`;  But why? as I see it, Persron and Tourist implements the interface UTFSTRING, and for that it should be `? extends UTF-STRING`. What I miss?

Comment: Could you please rephrase your question, I could not understand a single word!

Comment: Why don't you provide an example where we don't have to assume the impossible? Would make copying and playing with it easier. (This issue is what keeps me from spending time with this question.)

Comment: Still it's same Tom, anyway, Person and Tourist implements Identifiable not UTFString. And by your code UTFString isn't an interface it is a class which extends String class means it is a type of String. And by saying type of Y what do you mean? like what type of class Y is? that would depend on does Y is a normal class or does it extends any other class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Person` and `Tourist` implement `Identifiable<String>` and `Identifiable<UTFString>` - the same generic interface, but with different type parameters. The type parameters are `String` and `UTFString`. These two classes are both subclasses of `String` and superclasses of `UTFString`, so *both* `? extends String` and `? super UTFString` will be allowed. The difference between them is what you can do with `z`: with `? extends String`, you may not call methods that take the generic type as a parameter; with `? super UTFString`, you may not call methods that return the generic type. Since you call `z.setId()`, which seems to take the generic type as a parameter, this excludes `? extends String`.

Answer (score 0):

If `z` was `Identifyable<UTFString>`, then  `z = new Person();` should not compile, as `Person` does not extend `Identifyable<UTFString>`.

I should possibly note that the notion of a `UTFString` seems rather confused - Strings do not have an encoding in Java. (They are always in Unicode. The only thing that can have an encoding is a sequence of bytes.)

Comment: Perhaps it's a UTF8Encoded string? (Java's String -- which is final, so it can't be the String above -- is quite wasteful memory-wise for the English language, for instance. Also, Java's String is really UTF-16 Encoded (because it *utilizes* surrogate pairs), except that it can contain invalid sequences ;-)

Comment: @pst Could be, yes. I guess from the quality of the question I just assumed the worst.

Answer (score 0):

I think you asked why you should use ? super UTF-STRING instead of ? extends UTF-STRING.
If this is the question you can also use a Identifiable when declaring z.
Person and Tourist implement it so you can use it for both.
Honestly I think that a Tourist should extend a Person, because all the Tourists are Persons (in lexical meaning) so I'd declare

public class Person implements Identifiable  { . . . }

public class Tourist extends Person { . . . }

Person z = null;
if ( . . . ) {
     z = new Person ( ) ;
} else {
    z = new Tourist ( ) ;
}
z.setId(new UTFString(…))